# C# FileSystemWatcher.Renamed NoRename not in context

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I am writing a hotfolder application to pull files as they enter an FTP site and move them to another server. On large file the file is name file.FilePart until complete so I need to catch the file rename. I am using FileSystemWatcher to do this and it works fine except for the Rename. I am using VS 2022 V 17.4.3, .Net 7.0 and C# 11.0 but I get Name 'NoRename' not in the current context. Thisis driving me nuts. Anybody have an idea what I am doing wrong.

I have tried uaing NoRename and Rename but neither works, I have changed .net version and C# version and updated VS. Here is the code up to the error.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Renci.SshNet;
using Renci.SshNet.Sftp;

namespace Hotfolder1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
        
            string HFBase = @"c:\FTP"; 
            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(HFBase);
            watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
            watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(FileCreated);
            watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(*NoRename*);
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

`

Comment: Where is your method called `NoRename`?

Comment: You appear to have successfully created an event handler for `Created`.  You need to do something similar for `Renamed`.

Comment: I am such an idiot at times. In looking at the event handler subroutine for the 100th time i found the typo creating the problem. Many thanks for prompting me to look at the sub again.